# @using can not find a folder that exists and the path is correct

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

In asp.net core I am trying to add a folder with `@using` in my `_ViewImports.cshtml`, however it seems that it is invisible to it, even though there is absolutely no reason for it to be invisible.

[Visual Studio solution and _ViewImports.cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUx2H.png)

Comment: Usings do not add a "folder" but a namespace. What is the namespace in that file there?

Comment: Good lord, thank you! For some reason the namespce was OnlineCardShop.Models and not OnlineCardShop.Models.Dealers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the namespace was incorrect. Changing the namespace in the `BecomeDealerFormModel.cs` from `OnlineCardShop.Models` to `OnlineCardShop.Models.Dealers` fixed it.